# Can't open a pdf file that I copeid from Android data folder

Tags: file-extension, fileopener2

I have a study app that provides PDFs but these PDFs only open in the app itself even after downloading, like YouTube offline videos, I looked up for these saved files in the app data folder, but they have no extension. I tried different extensions so that I could open them, but they aren't opening.
Please help if you know how to open, I'm attaching a file via [a Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9coPn2dW-9Ogwi1u87lDHD7Ele7o_0y/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

In some systems file extensions may not be visible.

For a viewer to open a PDF, ideally it should have a file extension as .pdf.

Likewise if the file is badly defined or broken the PDF may not start with %PDF-1.7 or similar in the first line.

If a file is broken in transit parts may have become garbled and that seems to be what's happened to your personal copy of now broken pdf.
[image]

You need to repair the corruption by overwrite and save as repaired.pdf
[image]

[image]